# Leetcode Word Search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, backtracking

I am currently trying to solve the [Word Search problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search/). The question is as follows:

> Given an m x n grid of characters board and a string word, return true if word exists in the grid.

My attempt is as follows:

```py
class Solution:
    def exist(self, board: List[List[str]], word: str) -> bool:
        def backtrack(loc: tuple, i: int) -> bool:
            x = loc[0]
            y = loc[1]
            if loc in seen:
                return False
            if  x >= len(board) or y >= len(board[0]):
                return False
            if 0 > x or 0 > y:
                return False
            if board[x][y] != word[i]:
                return False
            if i >= len(word)- 1:
                return True
            seen.add(loc)
            return backtrack((x+1, y), i+1) or backtrack((x-1, y), i+1) or backtrack((x, y-1), i+1) or backtrack((x,y+1), i+1)
        for i in range(len(board)):
            for j in range(len(board[i])):
                if board[i][j] == word[0]:
                    seen = set()
                    if backtrack((i, j), 0):
                        return True
        return False
```

Now I am able to solve the problem if I was to edit the board input to check if a state was visited but I would prefer not to modify the input array so I chose to use a hash set to do it. However I'm unable to properly implement the check and that is why my code is failing so I was hoping that someone could help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For backtracking algorithms, you have to take back the "move" you've made. So in this case, you have to remove the `loc` from `seen` after you make the recursive calls. Here is a proposed simple fix:

```py
class Solution:
    def exist(self, board: List[List[str]], word: str) -> bool:
        def backtrack(loc: tuple, i: int) -> bool:
            x = loc[0]
            y = loc[1]
            if loc in seen:
                return False
            if  x >= len(board) or y >= len(board[0]):
                return False
            if 0 > x or 0 > y:
                return False
            if board[x][y] != word[i]:
                return False
            if i >= len(word)- 1:
                return True
            seen.add(loc)
            res = backtrack((x+1, y), i+1) or backtrack((x-1, y), i+1) or backtrack((x, y-1), i+1) or backtrack((x,y+1), i+1)
            seen.remove(loc)  # Removes loc from seen
            return res
        for i in range(len(board)):
            for j in range(len(board[i])):
                if board[i][j] == word[0]:
                    seen = set()
                    if backtrack((i, j), 0):
                        return True
        return False
```